# Google Analytics combine statistics from different URLs

Tags: google-analytics, wordpress, analytics, statistics, page-views

I am working as a student assistent for a University on a Wordpress website that contains courses.

They want for each course a overview of pageviews. The problem I am facing is that the course contains multiple different URLs which are not relatable to eachother.

The URLs are as followed (examples):

- www.website.com/course/Statica/index.html
- www.website.com/course/course-lectures/1-introductie.html
- www.website.com/course/course-lectures/2-Krachtendiagrammen.html
- www.website.com/course/course-readings/3-Wrijvingscoefficient.html

Is there a way to 'combine' statistics and generate a report for the course 'Statica'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a report that filter the pageviews of this particular group of pages. Call the report “Statica Report”.

I will recommend following [this tutorial](http://mudd.com/blog/tracking-subsets-of-pages-with-google-analytics/) on how to do this

Add as many filters as pages you need to group, also try to identify common patterns or URL similarly to simplify the creating filter process.

Comment: Excuse me for my late response, but I've found the solution via your link! Found correlations in the urls with the combination of regex. Thank you!